# Vector space polynomials

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

Being trying to solve this problem on vector space but don't know how to begin with it. Tried using my knowledge on vector space but its not working because I don't know much about vector space polynomials.
Express each of the following polynomials as a linear combination of the basis $2-x^2$, $x^3-x$, $2-3x^2$ and $3-x^3$, and the polynomials are:

**a.** $\;x^2$ 
**b.** $\;1+x$ 
**c.** $\;x^3\,$ 
**d.** $\;x+x^2$

Any idea about how to solve this problem please?

Comment: If it's the polynomials that are throwing you off, try rewriting $1$ as $(1,0,0,0)$, $x$ as $(0,1,0,0)$, $x^2$ as $(0,0,1,0)$ and $x^3$ as $(0,0,0,1)$, and see if you can solve the problems in this notation.

Comment: You have a misunderstanding in the title. The polynomials *form* a vector space. There are no "vector space polynomials".

Comment: I wrote out the canonical basis for p^4 which is (1, x, x^2, x^3) and have decomposed vectors of the system by the canonical basis to obtain (2,0,2,3) (0,-1,0,0) (-1,0,-3,0) (0,1,0,-1), please how do I express the polynomials as a linear combination of these basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:   by simple elimination, let $p=2-x^2, q = x^3-x, r = 2-3x^2, s = 3-x^3\,$, then:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
3p-r &= 4 \\
q+s &= - x+3 \\
p-r &= 2 x^2 \\
s &= -x^3 + 3
\end{align}
\end{cases}
\quad\iff\quad
\begin{cases}
1 &= \frac{1}{4}(3p-r) \\
x \;\;= 3-q-s &= \frac{3}{4}(3p-r)-q-s \\
x^2 &= \frac{1}{2}(p-r)\\
x^3 \;\;= 3 - s &= \frac{3}{4}(3p-r) - s
\end{cases}
$$

Given any polynomial $\,f(x)=a\cdot x^3+b\cdot x^2+c\cdot x+ d \cdot 1\,$ in the canonical base, replacing $\,1, x, x^2, x^3\,$ with the expressions above will give $\,f\,$ as a linear combination of $\,p,q,r,s\,$.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very helpful hint. So I can say the solution to the first question is 1/2(p-r) and the second question by simply substituting the expression for 1 and x then add together?

Comment: @user546520 Right. You may want to write as (for example) $\,x^2 = \frac{1}{2}p - \frac{1}{2}r\,$ in order to make it clear what each component is.

Comment: Alright. Thanks a lot